# How to install python weka wrapper on ubuntu 32 bit?

Tags: python, weka

The official website shows how weka-wrapper can install on ubuntu 64 bit. I want toknowhow it can be install on ubuntu 32 bit?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a compatibility issue you can install a wrapper from [here](https://github.com/chrisspen/weka):

```
sudo apt-get install weka libsvm-java

sudo pip install weka
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install python-weka-wrapper
```

I see no difference here. pip will cover the compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Before installing weka wrapper for python** you are suppose to install the weka itself using `sudo apt-get install weka` or build from source code and add the path the enviroment variable using **export wekahome="your weka path"** this will make sure you have the required weka jar file in the directory